# Searching menu items/titles in Joomla 1.5

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I've inherited a system built on Joomla 1.5 that I can't update to a newer version, so I have to make do for now.

Having got my head around the menu and url system I was trying to figure out if there is an easy way to search only the menu titles, essentially the pages in my site, and not just the articles.

The reason I ask is that I have some pages that have multiple articles (category blog layout) AND multiple modules, the current search results are correct but when clicked will return only that article, not the rest of the page that surrounds it.

Someone will probably be able to tell me that there is a tick box to do this somewhere or a simple hack in the code, but being unfamiliar with Joomla I have no idea how to go about it, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll make your life a lot easier and your Joomla site better if you develop your menu structure a lot like your data.

This means creating a menu item for every article or blog or category view, helps Joomla ascertain the ItemID for the view.  Armed with this it has a better understanding of what modules to render with it.

Or said another way...create a menu item for each article or category view.  You do not have to show them on the site.  Joomla will look for an associated menu item when rendering a page.  Armed with a menu item, you can dictate what modules are shown along with it through the properties of the modules.

Although I have no affiliation with NoNumber I would highly recommend downloading the Joomla1.5 version of Advanced Module Manager. This will give you far greater control over module placement.

Please be forewarned, this approach may change the URL structure of your articles which will lead to 404s for some content.  You may want to download the ported Joomla2.5 component called ReDirect.  This will help you manage those 404s.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what you've suggested is essentially what we have done, but there are several instances of multiple articles that need to be shown for a given menu item, we've got around this by grouping the articles together. I'm not sure we will be sticking with Joomla in the long term, definitely not staying with version 1.5.